# how to get data by finding all and finding one at the same time

Tags: meteor

In my project on the user edit page I would like to show the current role,wich i get by findOne byId,but I would also like to get all available roles so that I can choose, roles are in a separate collection, and I dont have a problem when displaying eather one...or all..

```
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                      <label>Email</label>
                      <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email" value="{{emails.[0].address}}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                      <label>Password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" id="password" value="{{password}}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                      <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="firstname" value="{{profile.name}}">
                  </div>



                  <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Current role:</strong>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="accountRole" value="{{roleName profile.role}}" checked>{{roleName profile.role}}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                    {{/with}}
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <form>
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Roles:</strong>
                      {{#each rolesInformation}}
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="accountRole" value="{{_id}}">{{roleName}}
                    </label>
                    {{/each}}</div>`
```

helpers look like this:

```
Template.editUser2.helpers({


user: () => {
return Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Session.get('id')});


},



playerInformation: () => {
return Players.find().fetch();


},


roleName: (id)=>{
return Roles.findOne({_id:id}).roleName;



 },


rolesInformation: () =>{
return Roles.find().fetch();


 },
```

when i run roleName or rolesInformation separateli it works fine...
whet both included i get "roleName not defined"

Comment: Can you see which roleName is undefined? You've got a helper called rollName, that returns the value of the rollName property, and then you've also got the rollName property in your #each block - so which one is coming up as undefined? Is there a more detailed error message you could include?

Comment: Undefined was rolesName from "rolesInformation" , but i'we found the error....it apears when using two helpers on a same collection(which i didn't know) i have to use this. so it was simply {{this.roleName}},and without roleName helper i've got the same result with only {{roleName}}